# jVectorMap: How to set scale if all values in the series are the same?

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I am passing values for all the countries in `ctrl.totalData` using the jVectorMap jQuery plugin.

The range of values is `[0, some maxValue]` and the scale I am using is `["#ffffff", "#84ce79", "#0a4f00"]`. When all the values in series are zero, all countries are colored as green(`#0a4f00`).

How do I make it to pick white(`#ffffff`) when all the values are zero?

```
$("#world-map-attacks").vectorMap({
  map: "world_mill",
  zoomOnScroll: false,
  backgroundColor: "#C8EEFF",
  series: {
    regions: [{
      values: ctrl.totalData,
      scale: ["#ffffff", "#84ce79", "#0a4f00"],
      normalizeFunction: "polynomial"
    }]
  }
});
```